# structure pointer field on a map in Golang

Tags: go

I want to include different structure pointer fields in the map as shown below. (Of course the code below doesnt work)

```
type StructA struct {

}
type StructB struct {
    
}

mymap := map[string]*struct{}{
    "StructA": StructA,
    "StructB": StructB,
}
```

Comment: You can't. Use `any` (`interface{}`).

Comment: `StructA` and `StructB` are distinct types. `struct{}` is a zero byte, empty struct (`a := struct{}{}`). They just aren't the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @icza said the element type of a map must be a specific type.  But this could be an interface that can store an object of different types. The type `any` (an alias for `interface{}` is in some ways like a pointer (though it also stores type info), so you could just do:

```
mymap := map[string]inteface{}{
    "StructA": StructA{},
    "StructB": StructB{},
}
```

To be a little safer you can restrict the types that can be added to the map to just the two structs.  To do this you need an interface which specifies a function that both the struct types implement.

```
type (
    Common interface{ ImplementsCommon() }
    A      struct{}
    B      struct{}
)

func (A) ImplementsCommon() {}
func (B) ImplementsCommon() {}

    mymap := map[string]Common{
        "A": A{},
        "B": B{},
    }
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/_15MXMnzkIX)